# Append Querystring key/value pair while using MVC ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, query-string, action-filter

I want to create my own `ActionFilter` which will append at the end of the URL a certain key/value pair (`GUID` in my case).

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If the key/value pair exists in the querystring, then what you need an ActionFilter for? Do you need the ActionFilter to add the append the querystring to the URL in case of a redirect? If that's the case ActionFilter is not the right choice.

Comment: I want to create a guid on the server side, save it in Session and append it to the request by QueryString

Comment: You can only change the query string by calling `Response.Redirect` but I don't think you want that. Use route data instead to transfer the guid to the view or wherever you need it.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. To which request do you want to append the GUID? Is there a RedirectToAction in your Action? Or, do you want the GUID to be added to the querystring when the form is submitted in your View? Providing more code would help to understand your problem.